# Different Virtual Environment for multiple projects

Tags: django, python-3.x, environment-variables, virtualenv

I'm new to environmental variable issues. I work on django. I saw some projects source code getting data from environmental variable. I successfully setup the variables. But problem is the variables setup globally. When I call the variable from another project same variables value. How can I setup the variable for virtual environment only?

Comment: Usually in Django we use a `local_settings.py`, and the `settings.py` file imports some overrides from that.  You don't need environment variables this way.

Comment: Can u give some instruction to do so.

Comment: I think variables value means value from installed package right ?

Comment: `ALLOWED_HOSTS= os.environ['ALLOWED_HOSTS']`